# Rename multiple columns at once in SparkR DataFrame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

How can I rename multiple columns in a SparkR `DataFrame` at one time instead of calling `withColumnRenamed()` multiple time? For example, let's say I want to rename the columns in the `DataFrame` below to `name` and `birthdays`, how would I do so without calling `withColumnRenamed()` twice?

```
team <- data.frame(name = c("Thomas", "Bill", "George", "Randall"),
  surname = c("Johnson", "Clark", "Williams", "Yosimite"),
  dates = c('2017-01-05', '2017-02-23', '2017-03-16', '2017-04-08'))
team <- createDataFrame(team)

team <- withColumnRenamed(team, 'surname', 'name')
team <- withColumnRenamed(team, 'dates', 'birthdays')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard R methods apply here - you can simply reassign `colnames`:

```
colnames(team) <- c("name", "name", "birthdays")
team
```

```
SparkDataFrame[name:string, name:string, birthdays:string]
```

If you know the order you could skip full list and

```
colnames(team)[colnames(team) %in% c("surname", "dates")] <- c("name", "birthdays")
```

You'll probably want to to avoid duplicate names though.